# Why I got ZERO_RESULTS for valid addresses in Sweden?

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I send this request https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:SE|locality:Huddinge|postal_code:14158&address=Sm%C3%A5brukets+Backe+30%2C+14158+Huddinge but I got zero result.

If I removed "postal_code:14158" it will work but It won't return the right postal code.

I got the same result for many valid addresses.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Geocoding API is designed to help people create maps. Google doesn't do address verification or validation.

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like a street address) into geographic coordinates (like latitude and longitude), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map. ([Google Geocoding API Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start))

In your case, it is best to simplify your search terms (drop the postal code, since that seems to work). You will still get fairly accurate results for placing markers on maps.

Also, you could [report](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?visit_id=1-636216737512545532-3772858462&rd=1) the information problem to Google Maps. They are responsive: they might update the service so the search returns something valid for your address search term.

If you need exact addresses or you need the postal code in all cases, try an address validation service, such as [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/). [Here is a demo](https://smartystreets.com/demo/api?auth-id=21102174564513388&country=SE&address1=Sm%C3%A5brukets%20Backe%2030%2C%2014158%20Huddinge&locality=Huddinge&administrative_area=&postal_code=14158&#international-street).

Full disclosure: I worked for SmartyStreets.